# am chart 5 Stacked column chart with line chart

Tags: amcharts5

I am trying to create a stacked column chart and trying to integrate a line chart on Y axis, Chart is rendering but line is not visible which is using opposite y axis value.

- latitudeSeries should create a line chart using the opposite y axis that is Y axis value on the right side. But it's not rendering the line chart though opposite y axis is rendered.

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
  #chartdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
  }
  </style>
  
  <!-- Resources -->
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Chart code -->
  <script>
  am5.ready(function() {
  
  // Create root element
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
  var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
  
  
  // Set themes
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
  root.setThemes([
    am5themes_Animated.new(root)
  ]);
  
  
  // Create chart
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
  var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    panX: false,
    panY: false,
    wheelX: "panX",
    wheelY: "zoomX",
    layout: root.verticalLayout
  }));
  
  
  // Add legend
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/legend-xy-series/
  var legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
    centerX: am5.p50,
    x: am5.p50
  }));
  
  var data = [{
    "year": "2021",
    "europe": 2.5,
    "namerica": 2.5,
    "asia": 2.1,
    "lamerica": 1,
    "meast": 0.8,
    "africa": 0.4,
  "latitude": 40.00
  }, {
    "year": "2022",
    "europe": 2.6,
    "namerica": 2.7,
    "asia": 2.2,
    "lamerica": 0.5,
    "meast": 0.4,
    "africa": 0.3,
    "latitude": 45.74
  }, {
    "year": "2023",
    "europe": 2.8,
    "namerica": 2.9,
    "asia": 2.4,
    "lamerica": 0.3,
    "meast": 0.9,
    "africa": 0.5,
    "latitude": 39.74
  }];
  
  
  // Create axes
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "year",
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
      cellStartLocation: 0.1,
      cellEndLocation: 0.9
    }),
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
  }));
  
  
  
  var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    min: 0,
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));
  

  
  var latitudeAxisRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {opposite:true});

var latitudeAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  renderer: latitudeAxisRenderer

  
}));

var latitudeSeries = chart.series.push(am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
  xAxis: xAxis,
  yAxis: latitudeAxis,
  valueYField: "latitude",
  valueXField: "year",
  tooltip:am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
    labelText:"latitude: {valueY}"
  })  
}));



latitudeSeries.strokes.template.setAll({ strokeWidth: 2 });

// Add circle bullet
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/#Bullets
latitudeSeries.bullets.push(function() {
  var graphics = am5.Circle.new(root, {
    strokeWidth: 2,
    radius: 5,
    stroke: latitudeSeries.get("stroke"),
    fill: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
  });

  graphics.adapters.add("radius", function(radius, target) {
    return target.dataItem.dataContext.townSize;
  })

  return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
    sprite: graphics
  });
});
latitudeSeries.data.setAll(data);
  // Add series
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
  function makeSeries(name, fieldName, stacked) {
    var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
      stacked: stacked,
      name: name,
      xAxis: xAxis,
      yAxis: yAxis,
      valueYField: fieldName,
      categoryXField: "year"
    }));
  
    series.columns.template.setAll({
      tooltipText: "{name}, {categoryX}:{valueY}",
      width: am5.percent(90),
      tooltipY: am5.percent(10)
    });
    xAxis.data.setAll(data);
    series.data.setAll(data);
    
    // Make stuff animate on load
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
    series.appear();
  
    series.bullets.push(function () {
      return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
        locationY: 0.5,
        sprite: am5.Label.new(root, {
          text: "{valueY}",
          fill: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText"),
          centerY: am5.percent(50),
          centerX: am5.percent(50),
          populateText: true
        })
      });
    });
  
    legend.data.push(series);
  }
  
  makeSeries("Europe", "europe", true);
  makeSeries("North America", "namerica", true);
  makeSeries("Asia", "asia", true);
  makeSeries("Latin America", "lamerica", true);
  makeSeries("Middle East", "meast", true);
  makeSeries("Africa", "africa", true);





  // Make stuff animate on load
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
  chart.appear(1000, 100);
  
  }); // end am5.ready()
  </script>
  
  <!-- HTML -->
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `xAxis` is a category axis, not a value axis. Thus, in your `latitudeSeries` settings, you must use `categoryXField` instead of `valueXField`.

For more readability, I recommend you to synchronize `latitudeAxis` and `yAxis` using `syncWithAxis`. You should also set transparency on your column series.

I edited your code and added these little corrections (with comments).

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<style>
  #chartdiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
  }
  </style>
  
  <!-- Resources -->
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/xy.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>
  
  <!-- Chart code -->
  <script>
  am5.ready(function() {
  
  // Create root element
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
  var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
  
  
  // Set themes
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
  root.setThemes([
    am5themes_Animated.new(root)
  ]);
  
  
  // Create chart
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
  var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
    panX: false,
    panY: false,
    wheelX: "panX",
    wheelY: "zoomX",
    layout: root.verticalLayout
  }));
  
  
  // Add legend
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/legend-xy-series/
  var legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
    centerX: am5.p50,
    x: am5.p50
  }));
  
  var data = [{
    "year": "2021",
    "europe": 2.5,
    "namerica": 2.5,
    "asia": 2.1,
    "lamerica": 1,
    "meast": 0.8,
    "africa": 0.4,
  "latitude": 40.00
  }, {
    "year": "2022",
    "europe": 2.6,
    "namerica": 2.7,
    "asia": 2.2,
    "lamerica": 0.5,
    "meast": 0.4,
    "africa": 0.3,
    "latitude": 45.74
  }, {
    "year": "2023",
    "europe": 2.8,
    "namerica": 2.9,
    "asia": 2.4,
    "lamerica": 0.3,
    "meast": 0.9,
    "africa": 0.5,
    "latitude": 39.74
  }];
  
  
  // Create axes
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
  var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
    categoryField: "year",
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {
      cellStartLocation: 0.1,
      cellEndLocation: 0.9
    }),
    tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
  }));
  
  
  
  var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
    min: 0,
    renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
  }));
  

  
  var latitudeAxisRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {opposite:true});

var latitudeAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  syncWithAxis: yAxis, // Synchronize axes to get a more readable grid
  renderer: latitudeAxisRenderer

  
}));

var latitudeSeries = chart.series.push(am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
  xAxis: xAxis,
  yAxis: latitudeAxis,
  valueYField: "latitude",
  categoryXField: "year", // Use categoryXField instead of valueXField
  tooltip:am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
    labelText:"latitude: {valueY}"
  })  
}));



latitudeSeries.strokes.template.setAll({ strokeWidth: 2 });

// Add circle bullet
// https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/#Bullets
latitudeSeries.bullets.push(function() {
  var graphics = am5.Circle.new(root, {
    strokeWidth: 2,
    radius: 5,
    stroke: latitudeSeries.get("stroke"),
    fill: root.interfaceColors.get("background"),
  });

  graphics.adapters.add("radius", function(radius, target) {
    return target.dataItem.dataContext.townSize;
  })

  return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
    sprite: graphics
  });
});
latitudeSeries.data.setAll(data);
  // Add series
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
  function makeSeries(name, fieldName, stacked) {
    var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
      stacked: stacked,
      name: name,
      xAxis: xAxis,
      yAxis: yAxis,
      valueYField: fieldName,
      categoryXField: "year"
    }));
  
    series.columns.template.setAll({
      tooltipText: "{name}, {categoryX}:{valueY}",
      width: am5.percent(90),
      tooltipY: am5.percent(10),
      // Set column and stroke transparency for more readability
      opacity: 0.75,
      stroke: "transparent"
    });
    xAxis.data.setAll(data);
    series.data.setAll(data);
    
    // Make stuff animate on load
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
    series.appear();
  
    series.bullets.push(function () {
      return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
        locationY: 0.5,
        sprite: am5.Label.new(root, {
          text: "{valueY}",
          fill: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText"),
          centerY: am5.percent(50),
          centerX: am5.percent(50),
          populateText: true
        })
      });
    });
  
    legend.data.push(series);
  }
  
  makeSeries("Europe", "europe", true);
  makeSeries("North America", "namerica", true);
  makeSeries("Asia", "asia", true);
  makeSeries("Latin America", "lamerica", true);
  makeSeries("Middle East", "meast", true);
  makeSeries("Africa", "africa", true);





  // Make stuff animate on load
  // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
  chart.appear(1000, 100);
  
  }); // end am5.ready()
  </script>
  
  <!-- HTML -->
  <div id="chartdiv"></div>
```